# How can I use session specific data files in javascript

Tags: javascript, sinatra

I am creating a web application using Ruby Sinatra.  However, I think this question is more related to html/javascript.

In the front end I am using d3.js for some pages.  I want to create and use data files based on user input.  So for each user session I want to create a data file for that session.

I think I can create the custom html/javascript for each request.

Is there any other way to do this, such as passing the file name to the javascript?

Comment: `sessionStorage` comes to mind

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessionStorage (some examples is here http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/)